# CakePHP 2.5.2 URL includes app path twice after authentication

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-acl

I have built a simple website and have added authentication using the ACL guides found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html").  I think I have followed it to the letter.

The issue I have is this:
Once logged in, if I try to access a valid url, the route folder is added again.
e.g. accessing:

```
 projectpath/controllerpath/action
```

redirects to

```
 projectpath/projectpath/controllerpath/action
```

Thee things I have noticed:

1. It only happens if a user is logged in.  If they are not logged in it correctly redirect to the login page.
2. Only on pages that are controllers have this happen.  If I put in an incorrect page, it throws the Missing Controller Exception.
3. Any pages I give public access to work OK.  It is only and only those that are not public.

**Edit:**

This morning I installed a fresh version of CakePHP 2.5.3.  I then manually copied across all my files excluding the routes file.  Still getting the same error.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

**Edit:**
I have progressed a little further with this.  I removed the ACL component and used the Auth Component.

The issue seems to only occur when a logged in user tries to access an unauthorised url.  From Cake

> property `AuthComponent::$unauthorizedRedirect`
>   Controls handling of unauthorized access. By default unauthorized user is redirected to the referrer URL or AuthComponent::$loginAction or ‘/’. If set to false a ForbiddenException exception is thrown instead of redirecting.

**In my App Controller**

```
    public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Auth' => array(
        'redirectUrl' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        ),
        'unauthorizedRedirect'=> false,// I have added this line
    'Session',
     'authorize' => array('Controller') 
    )
);
```

This is working (in that it does not redirect at all).  Can anyone explain how to get the unauthorised redirection to the correct route as per the documentation?

**Edit**
This is my beforeFilter in App Controller

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->allow('display');
    /*if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'apa'){

    $this->Auth->redirectUrl = "/apa";
    }else{
    $this->Auth->redirectUrl = "/test";
    }*/ //Moved logic to UserController
        parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

**Edit** UserController

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'apa'){

            $this->Auth->redirectUrl = "/apa";
                }else{
            $this->Auth->redirectUrl = "/test";
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl);
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to different pages depending upon certain conditions or do you want to just go to the same page each time (e.g. unauthorized request redirects user to homepage)?

Comment: I've added my beforeFilter which I am trying to use to route based on role - I'd like to redirect based on role if possible.  This beforeFilter is for when they log in however they are still redirected to the referral URL

Comment: How about moving the "authorize" property from "Session" to "Auth" (I think that's where it should go anyway) and put the code from your beforeFilter() method in your isAuthorized($user) method instead?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kvothe.  I moved Authorize to Auth and I get the following error `Authentication adapter "authorize" was not found.`  I can remove it completely and it has no adverse effect.  Working on your idea, I have removed the beforefilter text above and added it into my UserController

Comment: were you able to solve this? Facing a similar problem -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379782/cake-php-2-x-project-redirecting-to-wrong-url-after-acl-implementation?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the loginAction and loginRedirect properties on your AuthComponent initialization, like this:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'),    // redirected here after login success
    'logoutRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action' => 'login',
        'home'
    ),
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
        )
    ), ...
```

Further, AuthComponent::redirectUrl is a method, not a property, and it is deprecated since v2.3.

Ref here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html